# Calculate Yearly Salary

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which I am storing information of employee and his/her salary. I wanted to calculate yearly salary of the employee from the date he/she was hired. I was able to get what I needed by the help of some guy here but one thing I can't solve is that if an employee was hired in jan 2018 and his/her salary isn't processed yet as salary get's processed after month ends but it shows the salary of the employee. If the same employee was hired in 2017 it gives perfect result.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeInfo](
    [EmpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [MonthlySalary] [int] NULL,
    [DOJ] [date]
    )
```

The data is given below:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeInfo] VALUES (1, 'Ahmad', 'Usman', '20000', '2016-06-01')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeInfo] VALUES (2, 'Erick', 'Ortiz', '18000', '2018-01-01')
```

Query I have derived so far:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT I.EmpID,
           I.FirstName,
           I.LastName,
           I.MonthlySalary,
           I.DOJ, 
           cntr = 1,
           SalaryMonth = DOJ
     FROM EmployeeInfo I 

     UNION ALL

     SELECT e.EmpID,
            e.FirstName,
            e.LastName,
            e.MonthlySalary,
            e.DOJ, 
            cntr = cntr + 1,
            Dateadd(month, cntr, e.DOJ)
     FROM  cte c
           JOIN EmployeeInfo e ON c.EmpID = e.EmpID
     WHERE  Dateadd(month, cntr + 1, e.DOJ) < DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(Getdate())),Getdate()))
SELECT EmpID,
       FirstName+' '+LastName [Employee Name],
       [DOJ],
       [Year] = Year(SalaryMonth),
       MonthlySalary, 
       YearlySalary = SUM(MonthlySalary),
       TotalSalary = Sum(Sum(MonthlySalary)) OVER(partition BY EmpID ORDER BY Year(SalaryMonth))
FROM cte
GROUP BY EmpID,
         Year(SalaryMonth),
         MonthlySalary,
         FirstName,
         LastName,
         [DOJ]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please don't make a complex one which I may not be able to understand at all.

Regards

Comment: @Sreenu131 That clause would need to go in the` WHERE` clause, not the `HAVING` (and would also not be SARGable).

Comment: Add WHERE ([DOJ])<DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(Getdate())),Getdate()) clause before Group by

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line? : 
Dateadd(month, cntr + 1, e.DOJ) < DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(Getdate())),Getdate()))

Comment: @holder I'm getting the number of months for which I need to calculate salary.

Comment: @doonie-darkoo, suppose you process this query on 5th March 2018, what is expected result? One row for Emp Id = 2 with monthlysalary = 18000 and yearlysalary = 36000? Is that a correct understanding?? If yes, the query would need modifications.

Comment: @Raska Yes that's what supposed to be the output.

Comment: Ok... I have posted the query... you can check out.

Comment: @Raska Have you updated your query ?

Comment: Yes Doonie Darkoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if hire date is more than one month with [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)

```
where DATEDIFF (month, DOJ, GETDATE()) > 1
```

Here is full working code:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT I.EmpID,
           I.FirstName,
           I.LastName,
           I.MonthlySalary,
           I.DOJ, 
           cntr = 1,
           SalaryMonth = DOJ
     FROM EmployeeInfo I 

     UNION ALL

     SELECT e.EmpID,
            e.FirstName,
            e.LastName,
            e.MonthlySalary,
            e.DOJ, 
            cntr = cntr + 1,
            Dateadd(month, cntr, e.DOJ)
     FROM  cte c
           JOIN EmployeeInfo e ON c.EmpID = e.EmpID
     WHERE  Dateadd(month, cntr + 1, e.DOJ) < DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(Getdate())),Getdate()))
SELECT EmpID,
       FirstName+' '+LastName [Employee Name],
       [DOJ],
       [Year] = Year(SalaryMonth),
       MonthlySalary, 
       YearlySalary = SUM(MonthlySalary),
       TotalSalary = Sum(Sum(MonthlySalary)) OVER(partition BY EmpID ORDER BY Year(SalaryMonth))
FROM cte
WHERE DATEDIFF (month, DOJ, GETDATE()) > 1
GROUP BY EmpID,
         Year(SalaryMonth),
         MonthlySalary,
         FirstName,
         LastName,
         [DOJ]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may give you a better performance. Please check with the data that you have) :-

```
declare @CurrentYear int;
declare @CurrentMonth int;
set @CurrentYear = Datepart(Year, GetDate()) ;
set @CurrentMonth = Datepart(Month,GetDate()) ;

with EmpYears AS (
select e.EmpID,
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.MonthlySalary,
    e.DOJ,
    @CurrentYear 'JYear',
    Case when datePart(Year, e.DOJ) = @CurrentYear 
        then ((@CurrentMonth  - datepart(month, e.DOJ)) * e.MonthlySalary )
        else (@CurrentMonth -1) * e.MonthlySalary  end 'YearlySalary'
from EmployeeInfo e 
UNION ALL
select e.EmpID,
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.MonthlySalary,
    e.DOJ,
    JYear - 1 'JYear',
    Case when datePart(Year, e.DOJ) = JYear - 1
        then (12 - datepart(month, e.DOJ) +1) * e.MonthlySalary
        else 12 * e.MonthlySalary  end 'YearlySalary'
from EmployeeInfo e
inner join EmpYears ey on e.EmpId = ey.EmpId where ey.JYear > DatePart(Year, e.DOJ)
)
    select EmpID,
   FirstName+' '+LastName [Employee Name],
   DOJ, JYear 'Year', MonthlySalary,
   Sum(YearlySalary) 'YearlySalary', 
   Sum(Sum(YearlySalary)) OVER(partition BY EmpID ORDER BY JYear) 'TotalSalary'
from EmpYears 
group by EmpID,
 FirstName,
 LastName,
 JYear, DOJ, MonthlySalary
order by EmpId, JYear
```

Comment: Post owner haven't asked about employees who hired in previous years. He asked about employees who have worked more than 1 month.